# how Can I fix non-scalar type conversion error

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to write an ICMP ping code in C.

The following code works very well:

```
int main(){ 
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  hname = gethostbyname("192.168.1.5");
  bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)hname->h_addr;
  ping(&addr);
}
void ping(struct sockaddr_in *addr){    
   sendto(sd,&pckt,sizeof(pckt),0,(struct sockaddr*)addr,sizeof(*addr))
}
```

But when I removed the parameter of function ping as following, compile failed.

```
int main(){ 
  ping();
}
void ping(){
   struct sockaddr_in addr;
   hname = gethostbyname("192.168.1.5");
   bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)hname->h_addr;
   sendto(sd,&pckt,sizeof(pckt),0,(struct sockaddr*)addr,sizeof(*addr))
}
```

The error was:`error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘struct sockaddr_in’)`
When I removed the * in sendto() function it still compiled error as:

```
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

btw, I created struct sockaddr_in in ping() function, because I need to do multiple process and need to avoid share the same struct by multiple processes.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a struct and a pointer to a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in the pointer to 'struct sockaddr_in addr'. I did some other fixes. You must be root to run this code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void ping(char *, int);
int main(){
    ping("data", 4);
}
void ping(char * pckt, int size){
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    struct hostent * hname = gethostbyname("localhost");
    memcpy(&addr.sin_addr, hname->h_addr, hname->h_length);
    int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if (sd >= 0) {
        if (sendto(sd,&pckt,size,0,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr)) > 0) {
            printf("send ok\n");
        } else {
            printf("send error\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("socket error\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Just confused that why sendto() function needs converting sockaddr_in to sockaddr?

Answer (score 1):

Why you have

```
struct sockaddr_in *addr
```

in the upper one as argument

but

```
struct sockaddr_in addr
```

in the failed one?

why not define addr as struct pointer ?

Comment: I create struct sockaddr_in in ping() function and get ride of the parameter way,  because I need to do multiple process and need to avoid sharing the same struct by multiple processes.

Comment: It's not about where you create it, it's about the TYPE of addr.  Why the first addr is a pointer to struct, but it becomes only a struct instead of a pointer to struct in your failed example?

Comment: If you were to define it as a pointer, how would you initialize it? That is, where would it point to?

Comment: I think in the sendto(), you need the address of the struct, that's why you need to pass a pointer (which stores its address)
but maybe you can try to use & to simply get its address...
 :  sendto(sd,&pckt,sizeof(pckt),0,(struct sockaddr*)(&addr),sizeof(*addr))

Comment: You need to define `addr` as an actual structure and pass `&addr` to `sendto()`.